# TypeError: create_superuser() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'first_name' and 'last_name'

Tags: python, django, authentication

I've checked other questions with same problem and tried solving with the solutions but none helped.
I neither see 'First Name' nor 'Last Name' input while creating a super user in the terminal
I've been following this tutorial 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HshbjK1vDtY&t=3422s' but the tutor doesn't face any problem while doing the exactly same thing I'm doing so there's nowhere I could find solution

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import(
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, email, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an first name")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an last name")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.set_password(password)
        user.staff = is_staff
        user.admin = is_admin
        user.active = is_active
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            password=password,
            is_admin=True,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_first_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.last_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

I've imported this in admin.py 
admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .forms import UserAdminChangeForm, UserAdminCreationForm
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

User = get_user_model()


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'admin')
    list_filter = ('admin', 'staff', 'admin')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin', 'staff', 'active')}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)


# Remove Group Model from admin. We're not using it.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Answer (score 6):

`REQUIRED_FIELD` should be `REQUIRED_FIELDS`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS

Comment: I wonder why it didn't give me syntax error when I misspelled the word. My django version is 2.2.7.

Comment: You can define any attribute/variable spelled however you want, it's not a syntax error to define a new attribute spelled slightly differently to another.

Comment: So I was declaring another variable as REQUIRED_FIELD instead of modifying REQUIRED_FIELDS?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what was happening

Answer (score 1):

create_superuser() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'name', 'birthday', 'phone', and 'gender'

have added `REQUIRED_FIELDS`  in extended user model and It works.

'''
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','birthday','phone','gender']
'''

Answer (score -2):

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    .......
    .......

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    .......
    .......
```

Here, first_name and last_name is required means, when you try to create superuser, django ask for first and last name. look below for full code.

```html
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True, default=False, blank=False,
                              null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # a admin user; non super-user
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # a superuser
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # notice the absence of a "Password fields", that is built in.
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # Email and password are required by default
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    # this is UserManager objects that inherit user manager of django through above code
    objects = UserManager()
    # .create_superuser(email, first_name, last_name)

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.first_name, self.last_name

    def get_first_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.last_name

    def get_email(self):
        return self.email

    def get_username(self):
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email, self.first_name, self.last_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"

        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perm(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permission to view the app 'app_label'?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staffuser(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.is_staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.is_superuser

    @property
    def user_status(self):
        return self.is_active
```

In this code your username will be email, i replace username field with email so user can't use extra fields.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.